How can I change/add to a hydraulic control valve to stop feeding via a laser or similar sensor
I have a manually operated hydraulic valve that feeds a log into a wood processor.  There is a adjustable plate that stops the log once you hit the desired length.  The problem is - the logs can weigh enough to move the stop plate, and bend it if the log moves fast enough.
Is there a way to remove the plate and install a sensor that will read that the log is in the correct position and stop the manual hydraulic valve?  The feed rate of the log can be slowed down, I just want to look at other options for measuring and stopping.
Thanks for your time

A photo of the setup wood be nice. (I know!) Is there an electrical power source (DC or AC) on the machine?

So companies like Mannesman-Rexroth have many valves with control circuits, all is possible.

You can use a garage door sensor. They usually send a 20 volt on/off signal when an object interrupts the laser beam..
Here is a sample from Amazon.
'

